# How to install plasma 5 on fedora 21?

Tags: linux, installation, desktop, fedora, kde-plasma

I'm using Fedora 21

```
kernel-core-3.19.3-200.fc21.x86_64
kde-workspace-4.11.16-3.fc21.x86_64
```

I don't know which version is my plasma, but these package installed:

```
kde-plasma-nm-pptp-0.9.3.5-7.fc21.x86_64
kde-settings-plasma-21-3.fc21.noarch
kdeplasma-addons-libs-4.14.3-3.fc21.x86_64
plasma-scriptengine-python-4.11.16-3.fc21.x86_64
kde-plasma-nm-openconnect-0.9.3.5-7.fc21.x86_64
kde-plasma-nm-0.9.3.5-7.fc21.x86_64
kde-plasma-nm-openswan-0.9.3.5-7.fc21.x86_64
kde-plasma-nm-vpnc-0.9.3.5-7.fc21.x86_64
kde-plasma-folderview-14.12.3-1.fc21.x86_64
kdeplasma-addons-4.14.3-3.fc21.x86_64
kde-plasma-nm-l2tp-0.9.3.5-7.fc21.x86_64
kde-plasma-nm-openvpn-0.9.3.5-7.fc21.x86_64
```

- How can i update to Plasma 5?
- Is there any conflicts with the packages i already installed?
- Should i remove kde4 first and install kde framework 5?

Comment: Flagging as off-topic because this question is not related to programming.

Comment: @tversteeg So shall i ask somewhere else?

Comment: You can ask it on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @tversteeg well, thanks~ StackExchange is really a huge site.

Comment: I've tried this and was not pleased with the result, it was still buggy. Upgrading to fedora beta 22 gives you a more stable Plasma 5 experience. (However, because of the current unavailability of RPMFusion, popular packages like VLC are not yet available on F22B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer elsewhere.

- First, install package dnf-plugins-core. you can install it by typing command:

  `sudo yum install dnf-plugins-core`
- update your fedora 21 packages to the most recent by entering command:

  `sudo dnf update`
- Now, add the repository KDE Plasma 5 for fedora 21 with the following command:

  `sudo dnf copr enable dvratil/plasma-5`
- Type the following command, if you want to install/upgrade kde plasma 5 in fedora 21.

  `sudo yum install plasma-5`
- Then reboot.

Ref: [How to Upgrade KDE Plasma 4 to KDE Plasma 5 in Fedora 21 KDE](http://linuxscoop.com/video/how-to-upgrade-kde-plasma-4-to-kde-plasma-5-in-fedora-21-kde)